# uninstalling all git mac

Tags: git, macos

I am currently trying to uninstall properly all gits on my computer so that I can re-install it, because I think I messed with different installs and all (for instance, it seems like I only have one big repository on my computer, which makes no sense to me). 
I read posts and tried to remove it safely, by running the uninstall.sh in the console: I removed the git in /usr/local/bin

However when checking :

- **git status** still returns something
- **which git** returns **/usr/bin/git**. So I conclude that I somehow had 2 gits (this one probably coming from Xcode).

Could someone advice me on how to clean properly my computer so that I can make a brand new start ? I really have been struggling with that for a while now (and wouldn't **sudo -rm** the second git).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply delete the cloned repositories. When you do a fresh install, you can clone them again and track whatever branches you want to. Deleted a clone repository will not affect in any way the work of the other contributors, not the Git server itself.

If you want to uninstall git, try with homebrew - `brew uninstall git`.